# Asp.Net Mvc4 WebSecurity How to activate or deactivate a user account

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, websecurity

I have create an account in mvc4 using the websecurity class as follow :

```
 WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password,
  new {  
           EmailAddress = model.EmailAddress, 
           ContactNo = model.ContactNo,
           Password = model.Password
       });
```

My user have created successfully ...
now i want to : 
activate/deactivate a user whenever i wish.

so that user login only if  his account is active otherwise he shouldn't be able to login .

How can i achieve this?

Comment: you can use [Authorize(Roles = "ActiveUser")] attribute on action.

Comment: i dnt want that,i need to activate and deactive and when user try to login a message must be shown to user that your account is not active...

Comment: you can get user with GetUser() and apply check on column basis that user is active or not and return custom message accordingly

Comment: is there any built in method to activate and deactivate an account ...

Comment: no you can just check on top of action with attribute. Otherwise check it while getting the details of user

Comment: @vishuminhas I think do it like my answer. Please see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UserProfile` class for do it. This class located in the `AccountModels` class which acts as a profile table for each user account. It is here that you'd typically want to include a property named `IsActive`.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
  [key]
  [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

You can change `IsActive` property and check it in `login` action.

See **[this post](https://forums.asp.net/post/5701620.aspx)** for more information.